# dojo.xhrGet parsing script tags

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I have code similar to

```
var targetNode = dojo.byId('xyz'); 
var xhrArgs = { 
url: 'Welcome.do?call=JS',  
  preventCache: true,   
load: function(data){    
  targetNode.innerHTML = data;   
  dojo.parser.parse('xyz');  
                    }
              }   
};   
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
```

But the html which is returned from the url call contains javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>doingsomething</script>
```

and those blocks are never parsed and executed which causes problems as some dojo stores are defined in the them (among other things).

Is there a different function or different when you can replace a div with a server side call and yet have it processed as it the browser loaded it fully?

Comment: most probably I think you are looking for a JSONP call.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "dojox/layout/ContentPane" instead of a plain div, you will get a property "executeScripts". This does what you want.

Comment: Doesnt appear to make any difference I added
    <div id='xyz' data-dojo-type='dojox.layout.ContentPane' executeScripts='true' >
  but the scripts didnt execute when the html is loaded

Answer (score 0):

From another stackoverflow post looks like prior to the parse I need to do this:

```
var arr = targetNode.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++) {
    eval(arr[n].innerHTML)
}
dojo.parser.parse('xyz');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to load a HTML page asynchronously and throwing it through `eval()` to load scripts over there.

The solution is quite simple, put the JavaScript onto the main page, for example:

```
var targetNode = dojo.byId('xyz'); 
var xhrArgs = { 
    url: 'Welcome.do?call=JS',  
    preventCache: true,   
    load: function(data){    
        targetNode.innerHTML = data;   
        dojo.parser.parse('xyz');  

        // Doing something
    }
};   
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
```

---

Another solution is like ben proposed, by using the `dojox/layout/ContentPane` widget, which has both the `url` and `executeScripts` property to load a HTML page asynchronously and execute scripts on it. However, the first solution is still better.

You're just making it very hard to debug code when you use `eval()` and it's also quite a performance issue compared to loading the scripts on your main page in stead of asynchronously loading it. The reason for this is that `eval()` is unpredicatable. Compilers always try to assume/predict as much as possible to improve speed, something which will not happen in this case.